# Jenkins and virtualbox plugin

Tags: plugins, jenkins, virtualbox

I'm trying to configure the Virtualbox plugin for Jenkins. I use the Jenkins 1.625 version and Tomcat8 on Debian jessy. VirtualBox is installed on the same host, and there are 4 virtual machines into.

I've launch my Virtualbox web server with this commands :

```
VBoxManage setproperty websrvauthlibrary null
vboxwebsrv -H MyHost
```

I've add a VirtualBox Cloud, the test connection works, I have a "Sucess".

But when I try to add a new Node, I add my VirtualBox Host in the list but after that there isn't any Virtual machines.

When i go to my Virtualbox web server I have only this :

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

<SOAP-ENV:Fault>
<faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
<faultstring>HTTP GET method not implemented</faultstring>
</SOAP-ENV:Fault>
```

There is my "New node" page.

[image: Jenkins]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found my answer recently. 
I solved it by add my default vm folder by setproperty to my virtualbox web server

```
VBoxmanage setproperty machinefolder /home/...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a permission issue. I had the same problem.

The user credentials you add for the VirtualBox Cloud must be the same user you used to create a vm. If they differ, no machines will be showed. This is because the machines of other users are not known to the current user.
Use `VBoxManage list vms` to see which vms are visible for the current user.